# Can we advertise Game On! etc. in the Community Bulletin?

Tags: feature-request, community-bulletin

This would be an awesome place to advertise forthcoming games to users of the site besides those that hang out in chat! Also worthy of inclusion: blog posts, chat event etc. We can has?

Comment: I whole heartedly support this idea!